# Updated data is not Showing using Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am Fresher in Code Igniter Framework. And I am using 2.2.6 codeigniter Framework. I Face a problem. My Project is proper Working on localhost But When I uploaded this Project on FTP And update some content But no changes occur But After Few minutes changes showing on live site. I don't know what is a problem with my project. This project is properly working on the Localhost

Comment: Is this as simple as refreshing your browser cache `ctrl+F5` Or possibly you have a cache like cloudflare getting in the way

Comment: yes, its browser cache, hard refresh plz

Comment: But sir, I deleted all cache And so many time Uses ctrl+5 but no changes occur, Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: what error display in your browser console ?

Comment: You should use newer version of codeigniter. May be base url issue? did you change the base url to your domain url.

Comment: Wolfgang yes, I gave changed the base url but same proplem arise.

Comment: Try call `header("Cache-Control: no-store");` at your controller and see if this help. Also check if you use codeigniter caching.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your server cache from Cpanel in "site improvement tools" panel in this panel super cache or some thing like that.